# Oracle 10g - bar chart of queries statistics for a set of tables

Tags: oracle, oracle10g, oracle-sqldeveloper

I would like to have a bar chart that compile usage statistics on a set of tables for a given period.

However I have to mention that I do not have rigths to access V$SEGMENTS or V$SESSION tables.

Is there a tool or a plugin in SQL Developer 3 that can achieve that even withouth those access?

Bump!

Comment: Can you add some details about what you want and why?  This question may be very difficult for two reasons.  1) There are several ways that Oracle stores queries, but they either do not capture everything or do not store for a long period of time.  2) Finding out which tables are used by a query is virtually impossible, although there are several ways to make a pretty good guess.

Comment: You may need to define more precisely what you mean by a query that is "made on" a set of tables - e.g. what if the query is based on a view? What if at execution stage the query never actually queries the table? What if the query doesn't touch the table, but does use an index on that table? What if the table is on another database (i.e. via a database link)?

Comment: thank you both of you for your comments, the question has been edited.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For DML stats you can use USER_TAB_MODIFICATIONS/ALL_TAB_MODIFICATIONS.

> Note: /*ALL_TAB_MODIFICATIONS describes tables accessible to the current user that have been modified since the last time statistics were gathered on the tables.
>   */

For query stat - only system view as V$SEGSTAT, v$db_object_cache, etc

Comment: when I do: `select * from V$SEGSTAT;` I got a table/view does not exist error. Does it means I dont have rights access to those tables?

Comment: Yes, you don't have rights. Run this query from dba or add grants to current user

Answer (score 1):

You can always query ALL_TABLES in order to know, which tables/views are available for you to select from. Remember, that view will show you both tables and views, even that is not important within your current case (join ALL_TABLES and ALL_SEGMENTS in order to distinguish, what is table, what is view)